# File uploading tags are ugly

Tags: html, file, upload, input

I'm not sure if this is possible without Flash...

Basically, is there a way to have a file upload dialog appear using an anchor, div, span, whatever, instead of `<input type="file" />`?
I want the user to be able to click on a link so they can choose a file to upload, instead of using the input tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input tag itself can be cleverly styled with a combination of markup, CSS and JavaScript (using jQuery, naturally).  See some examples [here](http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom) and [here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_custom_file_input_book_designing_with_progressive_enhancement/).  I agree that it's not as elegant as it *should* be, but it is doable.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using flash, you could use a Java applet, but in my opinion, that's even less user-friendly than a flash dropin.